# How to save memory while concatenating pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

I have around 100 tables that I want to read into one single dataframe. Currently, I read every table into its own dataframe and then concatenate them in the end. However, with the full amount of data, I run out of memory trying to concatenate them all because the all the data is copied into the new dataframe (data is around 8 GB, so fits into 16 GB RAM, but a copy won't fit).

Is there a possibility to "inplace" concat the dataframes to save memory?

For now I save the individual dataframes to disk, clear the memory and then concat them while they are being read from storage but I'd like to avoid the detour via disk if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Dask Python library, Dask is a parallel computing library that allows you to work with larger-than-memory datasets by breaking them up into smaller, more manageable chunks and processing them in parallel. A small example is provided below.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Create a list of dask dataframes
dfs = [dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1) for df in [df1, df2, df3, ...]]

# Concatenate the dask dataframes
result = dd.concat(dfs)

# Compute the result
result = result.compute()

# Display the resulting dataframe
print(result)
```

Hope this helps